# Symfony2: Form:bind data

Tags: php, forms, symfony, bind

I've got simple form

```
    $transformer = new ModuleToArrayTransformer($this->entityManager);
    $builder->add('modules', 'collection', array(
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'required' => false,
        'data' => $options['data'][0]->getModules(),
    ))
    ->add('save', 'submit', array(
        'label' => 'btn_update_and_edit_again',
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
        )
    ))
    ->addViewTransformer($transformer);
```

And controller for it:

> ```
>  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
> ```

```
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    $module = $em->getRepository('AcmeProjectBundle:Module')
        ->findBy(
            array(
                'user' => $userId,
                'project' => $projectId,
            )
        );

    if (!$module) {
        $module = $this->createAction($projectId, $userId);
    }

    $userData = $em->getRepository('AcmeSonataUserBundle:User')->find($userId);
    $projectData = $em->getRepository('AcmeProjectBundle:Project')->find($projectId);
    $form = $this->createForm(new ModuleType($em), $module, array('user' => $userData, 'project' => $projectData));
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'GET') {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
        }

    }
    return $this->render('AcmeProjectBundle:Module:edit.html.twig', 
        array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'projectId' => $projectId,
            'userId' => $userId,
        )
    );
```

The form is connected with another form. When I click on checkbox in the first form this form is generated - correctly. Until I try to `$form->bind($request);`

When I try to bind request it is showing sth like "This value is incorrect"

The `$_GET` seems to be fine

> ```
> array (size=1)
>   'acme_projectbundle_module' => 
> array (size=2)
>   'modules' => 
>     array (size=8)
>       'stats' => string '1' (length=1) 
>       'time' => string '1' (length=1) 
>       'issues' => string '1' (length=1) 
>       'metrics' => string '1' (length=1) 
>       'timeLine' => string '1' (length=1) 
>       'information' => string '1' (length=1) 
>       'status' => string '1' (length=1) 
>       'risks' => string '1' (length=1) 
>   'save' => string '' (length=0)
> ```

as well as the `$request` variable

If form looks exactly like my `$_GET` request what's the problem? As far as I know $_GET should contain the same values as `$request->parameters` field. How is is supposed to look like then? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind the form and check isValid when the request method is `GET` i.e. in the case when you just want to display the form to the user. And in that case you are bound to get the error

> "This value is incorrect"

because the `$request` does not contain any values.

So you should bind the form only when the data is submitted and not when the form is being displayed.

Comment: I forgot to add that for testing case I'm doing like this: if ($request->getMethod() == 'GET' && count($_GET)). The form is being binded only when I'm passing values.

Comment: the solution given here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161062/form-bind-not-binding-request-to-form-in-symfony-2-1fosrestbundle

Comment: Once again: getName returns 'acme_projectbundle_module'           var_dump($_GET) returns array (size=1)'acme_projectbundle_module' var_dump($request) returns query -> parameters -> array (size=1)
'acme_projectbundle_module' =>  Is that correct? Request go also field request -> parameters -> array (size=0) empty

Comment: try this: $form->bind($request->query->get('acme_projectbundle_module'));

Comment: Works. Sort of. The form values are changing BUT there is sill problem with form validation (false) and still got error This value is incorrect :) But so far - nice! Sth started to work! The question is: how to debug which value is incorrect? The strange thing is that I've got this message before whole form twice. @Edit: Form is incorrect even before binding. Any tips how am I suppose to valid it?

Comment: Form will always be incorrect before binding. You are supposed to bind it only when you have required data in required format readu with you in the form of request

Comment: But during form creation form is initialised with proper data. It's not enough? I don't actually the form creation flow for example when the dataTrasnformers are required? Druing binding? Do I need modelTransformer for binding?